# How do I fix the narrow aspect ratio of my icons after installing Yaru Colors?

Tags: icons, themes

After installing [Yaru colors](https://github.com/Jannomag/Yaru-Colors) , my icons look narrow.
How to fix it?

This is how my icons look

[image]

I use ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Seems you are using custom/external gnome-shell theme.. Is the narrowing of icons same with other themes/Default theme?

Comment: Problem is very likely caused by Yaru Colors.

Comment: Yes, I use cutom gnome-shell theme. The narrowing of the icons is the same with another gnome-shell theme or default gnome-shell theme. I also tried to change the applications theme but the problem still exists